# Incorrect Output for Bubble Sort

Tags: java, bubble-sort

I have been working on this code for about a week; I am trying to make a program that generate random numbers and then sort them using the Bubble method, but I get this message "Bubble Sort: [I@ad3ba4". Does anyone see what is wrong I feel like this is so simple but I just can't find the problem.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class sortLibrary {
    private static void bubbleSort(int[] list) {
        int n = list.length;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {
                if (list[j - 1] > list[j - 1]) {
                    temp = list[j - 1];
                    list[j - 1] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nBubble Sort: " + list);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Unsorted list:");
        Random numbers = new Random();
        int list[] = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            list[i] = numbers.nextInt(100);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + "  ");
        }
        bubbleSort(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString(list)` to print an array.

Comment: @YassinHajaj You just beat me to it! I just posted this in my answer before seeing this =P

Comment: @Jonathan At the end, you get the reps :). lol

Comment: @YassinHajaj I'm sorry I stole them from you. Next time, post an answer! Get that reputation!

Comment: @Jonathan, That's alright. Jk :).

Comment: @YassinHajaj you are awesome

Comment: @Jonathan you are awesome

Comment: @ShemaMartin I'm glad I helped! If you want to, please accept too... Like Yassin Hajaj said, I'm just out here to "get the reps" =P

Comment: @ShemaMartin, please click the check mark at the left of answer that helped you.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply print a list with a `println()`. That is only for strings.

Instead, replace `list` in your `println()` with `Arrays.toString(list)` to convert the array to a string for printing.

---

Or, you can print it out as an array, similar to @KyleGowen's answer. Here's an alternate form of a way to iterate over an array in Java easier:

```
String arrayToString = "";
for(int item : list) {
    arrayToString += item + ", ";
}
System.out.println("Bubble sort: [" + arrayToString.substring(0, arrayToString.length()-2) + "]");
```

This should also print it nicely.

See both of these at [TutorialPoint's online Java compiler](http://goo.gl/M9Qdgo).

Answer (score 1):

Now, you can not print Array in java just like that. If you want to print all array you need to use index or use something like this:

```
System.out.println("\nBubble Sort: " + Arrays.toString(list));
```

Also in your if statement you have `list[j - 1] > list[j-1]`. I think there will be `list[j - 1] > list[j]`. So your code looks like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class bubble {

    private static void bubbleSort(int[] list) {
        int n = list.length;
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (n - 1); j++) {

                if (list[j - 1] > list[j]) {
                    temp = list[j - 1];
                    list[j - 1] = list[j];
                    list[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nBubble Sort: " + Arrays.toString(list));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Unsorted list:");
        Random numbers = new Random();
        int list[] = new int[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            list[i] = numbers.nextInt(100);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.print(list[i] + "  ");
        }

        bubbleSort(list);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually printing out the memory address of your list with

```
System.out.println("\nBubble Sort: "+list);
```

You will most likely want to loop through the list and print out the values.  Something like:

```
System.out.print("\nBubble Sort: ");
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    System.out.print(list[i] + " ");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It would be easier to use a `for ... in` loop. Just saying.